# DSG 7 speed auto gear box: Can I move the gear stick from D to N while going down hill or coasting then back again, all while moving?

Tags: automatic-transmission

I have a 7 Speed DSG gearbox Golf Plus, Mark 6, 2012, TDI.

Will it harm the gearbox / transmission to move the gear stick from D to N while going down hill or coasting then back again, as a matter of saving fuel, all while moving?

Comment: I run a Skoda Octavia with DSG-7 which uses VW technology. It has a "mode" button which can be set to "economy". Then when no power is needed, the vehicle will coast (and so there is no engine braking). But although it is not illegal (in UK) to coast, if you have an accident you may be deemed to be "not in proper control of the vehicle."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should not hurt the gearbox but it won't save you any fuel either.  Modern engines, and a TDI (i.e. diesel) is in this category, use virtually no fuel when coasting.  If you shift to N you will likely use more fuel since the ECU will need to add fuel to keep the engine turning.

Comment: I definateley get better fuel economy on a tank when coasting   vs   not coasting at all on a tank . 

I've measured the average mpg across many tanks of fuel and I get around 46 - 48 mpg in town when coasting when thats feasiable   vs    40 - 42 mpg when leaving the car in gear all the time.

In both situations driving carefully.

Comment: .. when I change to Neutral for coasting revs drop to 800 rpm, and when looking at "Consumption" display consumption generally maxes out at or close to 200 mpg. For the same stretch of road if I stay in gear i'm going to get "Consumption = 60 mpg" or so. I'm getting more off a tank of fuel when I coast and the car computer is telling me that too.

Comment: Yes if you neutral-gear-coasting with distance long enough will use less fuel than engine-drag-coasting, with wet dsg it should not damaging anything, since the clutch disconnected from flywheel. Brake pad doesnt count.